# Pulling data from yahoo finance

Tags: excel, vba, yahoo-finance

I am trying to simply pull the name of a company from yahoo finance using its ticker symbol.  For some reason, the code below creates a URL that does not work.  Please help!

```
Sub LoadExternalData()
    Dim url As String
    url = "TEXT;http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=IBM&f=n"

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(url, Range("$C$3"))
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .Refresh
    End With
```

Comment: The code doesn't create a URL. You do, here: `url = "TEXT;http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=IBM&f=n"`. With that said, Yahoo goes to great lengths to protect the data it publishes for viewing from being scraped for free for the purpose of creating products Yahoo would rather like to sell for money. Hiding the URL is one of their tools. I've given up trying to download anything from Yahoo. There are many  sources for the same information that are more willing to share.

Comment: You can use `CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")` to get the response text using url "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IBM" and then extract the company name from the <Title> tag. `<title>International Business Machines (IBM) Stock Price, News, Quote &amp; History - Yahoo Finance</title>`?